# Dictionary removing duplicate along with subtraction and addition of values

Tags: python, dictionary

New to python here. 
I would like to eliminate duplicate dictionary key into just one along with performing arithmetic such as adding/subtracting the values if duplicates are found.

**Current Code Output**

> {('GRILLED AUSTRALIA ANGU',): (('1',), ('29.00',)), ('Beer', 'Carrot
>   Cake', 'Chocolate Cake'): (('10', '1', '1'), ('30.00', '2.50',
>   '3.50')), ('**Beer**', '**Beer**'): (('**1**', '**1**'), ('**3.00**', '**3.00**')), ('Carrot
>   Cake', 'Chocolate Cake'): (('1', '1'), ('2.50', '3.50')), ('Carrot
>   Cake',): (('1',), ('2.50',)), ('BRAISED BEANCURD WITH',): (('1',),
>   ('10.00',)), ('SAUSAGE WRAPPED WITH B', 'ESCARGOT WITH GARLIC H', 'PAN
>   SEARED FOIE GRAS', 'SAUTE FIELD MUSHROOM W', 'CRISPY CHICKEN WINGS',
>   'ONION RINGS'): (('1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1'), ('10.00', '12.00',
>   '15.00', '9.00', '7.00', '6.00')), ('**Beer**', '**Beer**', '**Carrot Cake**',
>   '**Chocolate Cake**'): (('**-1**', '**10**', '**1**', '**1**'), ('**-3.00**', '**30.00**', '**2.50**',
>   '**3.50**')), ('Beer',): (('10',), ('30.00',))}

What i want: example:

**SUBTRACTION FOR DUPLICATE**

> {'Beer': [9, 27]} , {'carrot cake': [1, 2.5]} , {'Chocolate Cake': [1,
>   3.5]}

notice that for duplicate item entry i trimmed Beer into one along with (10-1=9) for quantity amount and (30-3=27) for the cost. How do i automate this process?

**ADDITION FOR DUPLICATE**

> {'Beer': [2, 6]}

notice that I added beer and beer into one entry and along with the quantity (1+1) and cost (3+3=6)

**My code:**

```
import csv
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import re

d = {}

#open directory and saving directory
with open("rofl.csv", "rb") as f, open("out.csv", "wb") as out:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)
    writer = csv.writer(out)
    #the first column header
    writer.writerow(["item","quantity","amount"])
    groups = groupby(csv.reader(f), key=itemgetter(0))


    for k, v in groups:
        v = list(v)


        sales= [ x[1] for x in v[8:] ]
        salesstring= str(sales)

        #using re.findall instead of re.search to return all via regex for items
        itemoutput= re.findall(r"(?<=\s\s)\w+(?:\s\w+)*(?=\s\s)",textwordfortransaction)

        #using re.findall instead of re.search to return all via regex for amount aka quantity
        amountoutput= re.findall(r"'(-?\d+)\s+(?:[A-Za-z ]*)",textwordfortransaction)

        #using re.findall instead of re.search to return all via regex for cost

        costoutput= re.findall(r"(?:'-?\d+[A-Za-z ]*)(-?\d+[.]?\d*)",textwordfortransaction)

        d[tuple(itemoutput)] = tuple(amountoutput),tuple(costoutput)


        #writing the DATA to output CSV
        writer.writerow([d])
        #to remove the last entry else it would keep on stacking the previous
        d.clear()
```

link to csv file if needed
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1kSBxOGO4uJOFVZSWh2NWx6dHc

Comment: updated code pls refresh

Comment: Just for clarification: It seems like you _always_ want to add values, and some of the values just happen to be negative, right?

Comment: there exist 2 type of duplicate. first duplicate has positive value so just simply sum them up into one. whereas the second has negative value, so just simply deduct and trim into one key will do

Comment: updated current output section!

Comment: But for the second type that has a negative value, you can just add as well. `x + (-y)` is the same as `x - y`.

Comment: Do you want to preserve the individual transactions or just get a final total for each item?

Comment: Could you edit your question so that it is clear what your original code was, and how it looked after your edits based on the answers? Otherwise it looks like the answers did just take parts from your own existing code.

Comment: @Perlinn Don't vandalize your posts please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working with your current output as posted in the question, you can just [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the different lists of tuples of items and quantities and prices to align the items with each other, add them up in two `defaultdicts`, and finally combine those to the result.

```
output = {('GRILLED AUSTRALIA ANGU',): (('1',), ('29.00',)), ...}

from collections import defaultdict
prices, quantities = defaultdict(int), defaultdict(int)
for key, val in output.items():
    for item, quant, price in zip(key, *val):
        quantities[item] += int(quant)
        prices[item] += float(price)

result = {item: (quantities[item], prices[item]) for item in prices}
```

Afterwards, `result` is this: Note that you do *not* need a special case for subtracting duplicates when the quantity and/or price are negative; just add the negative number.

```
{'ESCARGOT WITH GARLIC H': (1, 12.0), 
 'BRAISED BEANCURD WITH': (1, 10.0), 
 'CRISPY CHICKEN WINGS': (1, 7.0), 
 'SAUSAGE WRAPPED WITH B': (1, 10.0), 
 'ONION RINGS': (1, 6.0), 
 'PAN SEARED FOIE GRAS': (1, 15.0), 
 'Beer': (31, 93.0), 
 'Chocolate Cake': (3, 10.5), 
 'SAUTE FIELD MUSHROOM W': (1, 9.0), 
 'Carrot Cake': (4, 10.0), 
 'GRILLED AUSTRALIA ANGU': (1, 29.0)}
```

---

If you want to keep the individual items separate, just move the declaration of `prices`, `quantities`, and `result` *inside* the outer loop:

```
for key, val in output.items():
    prices, quantities = defaultdict(int), defaultdict(int)
    for item, quant, price in zip(key, *val):
        quantities[item] += int(quant)
        prices[item] += float(price)
    result = {item: (quantities[item], prices[item]) for item in prices}
    # do something with result or collect in a list
```

Example result for the two-beer line:

```
('Beer', 'Beer', 'Carrot Cake', 'Chocolate Cake') (('-1', '10', '1', '1'), ('-3.00', '30.00', '2.50', '3.50'))
{'Chocolate Cake': (1, 3.5), 'Beer': (9, 27.0), 'Carrot Cake': (1, 2.5)}
```

If you prefer the `result` to group the items, quantities and prices together, use this:

```
items = list(prices)
result = (items, [quantities[x] for x in items], [prices[x] for x in items])
```

Result is this like this:

```
(['Carrot Cake', 'Beer', 'Chocolate Cake'], [1, 9, 1], [2.5, 27.0, 3.5])
```

Comment: nice! how do i call them out individually? ultimately i want to output them into csv file sectioning items, quantity and price based on {item': (1,5)} using         writer.writerow([d])

Comment: meaning in excel sheet it would be example: onion rings, choc cake... | 2, 2 | 13, 2 |

Comment: EXAMPLE in picture : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1kSBxOGO4uJSlJzYm83OER1MzA

Comment: @Perlinn What about the example? Is the output of the above code wrong? Do you also need help with writing to the output file? If so, please be more specific, or open another question for that.

Comment: I would like to filter dictionary key into item column where as value 1 into quantity column and value 2 into amount column. How do i do that with writer.writerow? http://i.imgur.com/pTTyVv8.jpg

Comment: such that it would become https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1kSBxOGO4uJSlJzYm83OER1MzA/view

Comment: FYI: I have updated my current code after your given input

Comment: NameError: name 'items' is not defined

Comment: updated current code - its the last gray code in the main section

Comment: solved already.                 result = (list(prices), [quantities[x] for x in d.items()], [prices[x] for x in d.items()])

Comment: @Perlinn See my edit. `Items` should be `list(prices)`. Using `d.items()` is probably not what you want to have.

Comment: Hello! i really appreciated for what you have done! I am near there already! i have updated the main section! do take a look

Comment: d.clear() such to prevent stacking entries iterating over and over again?

Comment: GOT IT ALREADY! THANKS WITH TEARS :(

Comment: @Perlinn It seems like the indentation is messed up in your updated code. Both `items = ...` and `writer....` should be on the same level of indentation as `prices, quantities = ...`